# Read object from file in flex

Tags: apache-flex

I write object in a file. first i convert the object to bitmap data then i write it in a file. Now I want to read object from the file so that it returns the original object. How can i do this?

Answer (score 0):

Probably it will help if you give more information about how you're writing the file.  Adobe's [BitmapData](http://www.adobe.us/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/display/BitmapData.html) documentation has [an example](http://www.adobe.us/livedocs/flex/3/langref/flash/display/BitmapData.html#includeExamplesSummary) of loading a GIF file then accessing its bitmap data.  However, [Loader](http://livedocs.adobe.com/flash/9.0/ActionScriptLangRefV3/flash/display/Loader.html#loadBytes%28%29) also supports JPG, PNG, and SWF files.